# Unable to echo certain PHP variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to accept input from a form and echo certain elements back into the html  page. But for some reason the variables I define aren't showing up.

Here is the code where I retrieve the form and set the variables:

```
<?php 
$firstName = $lastName = $email = $phone = $message = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $firstName = test_input($_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName = test_input($_POST['lastName']);
    $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    $phone = test_input($_POST['phone']);
    $message = test_input($_POST['message']);
}

function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
} ?>
```

And here is the form I'm using:

```
     <div style="width: 50%; margin:0 auto;border-style: solid;">
        <?php echo $_POST["message"]; ?>
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["$_PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="POST" id="contactForm">
            First Name: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
            Phone: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"><br>
            Leave a message:<br>
            <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit">   
        </form>
    </div>
```

The $_POST['message'] echos correctly, but I cannot figure out why the $message variable that I set in my PHP code will not echo. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi David, I think that the variable is lost when you arrive to the HTML so I would try to check if the other variables are being echo

Comment: Your `test_input` function does not return anything, yet you are assigning its return value to those variables … so effectively “nothing”.

Comment: Also `test_input()` is a terrible function name. That's not what it does, It should better be called `arbitrary_escaping()`. Leave a note whereever you found that recommended. See also: [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3126072)

Comment: I _really_ hope you're not using `test_input()` for escaping the data before any database operation, since it's _far_ from enough.

Comment: No, the data is not going to a database. I'm just trying to avoid script being injected into the html.

Comment: Also, thanks mario. I will check out the PHP sanitizing functions. I am very new to PHP so that should be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test_input doesn't return anything, so the contents of `$message` is NULL. $message *is* probably being echoed, it's echoing 'nothing'.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I looked for quite some time and can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

Your function does not return anything.

Here the updated code.

```
function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```